# Windows 10 virtual desktop - is there a setting to launch child process in same desktop as parent?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-desktop

I often run batch files processes which launch an application that appears, works then closes. It repeats many times.

My problem is that if I put my command line batch window to desktop 2, then switch back to desktop 1, the processes launched by the desktop 2 command line window appear on desktop 1 instead of the expected behaviour of appearing in the parent process's desktop 2.

It's a very annoying behaviour.
Can it be fixed/forced somehow?

Comment: Yes;  you can programmatically place a program on a specific virtual desktop but not with a batch file requires using the appropriate Windows library call in a real programming language

Comment: Thanks, so maybe I could create a launcher exe that I use from my batch. That would move the launched app to the launcher's caller's desktop.

Comment: ...and just found it that does it :  https://github.com/eksime/VDesk
Too bad launching an app to another desktop activates that desktop...